# Store list from file input stream, in a variable in LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have lets say the following list in a .txt file

`(5 3 1)`

All i am trying with following source code is to store the above list in a variable in LISP. Until the first format everything seems right. But then i realize that `*originalStateVar*` is not getting treated as a list with 3 atoms but as a list with 1 atom. Source code follows:

```
(defvar *originalStateVar*)
(defun fileInput ()
  (let ((i 1)(in (open *originalStateLocation* :if-does-not-exist nil)))
        (when in
            (loop
                for line = (read-line in nil)
                while line do 
                    (format t "~a~%" line)                ;debug line
                    (format t "i is <~a>~%" i)            ;debug line
                    (setf *originalStateVar* (list line)) ;storing list in variable
                    (setf i (+ i 1)))                     ;debug line
            (close in))
        (format t "originalStateVar is <~a>" (car *originalStateVar*))
        (format t "second element originalStateVar is <~a>~%" (cadr *originalStateVar*))
        (format t "third element originalStateVar is <~a>~%" (caddr *originalStateVar*))))
```

The output of the above code though is:

```
(5 3 1)
i is <1>
first element originalStateVar is <(5 3 1)>
second element originalStateVar is <NIL>
third element originalStateVar is <NIL>
```

All i can tell is that it stores the (5 3 1) as a single atom in a list, so it becomes something like `((5 3 1))` and that's why `cadr` returns `NIL`.

Any help on how to make `*originalStateVar*` get treated that way, would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- use `WITH-OPEN-FILE` instead of `OPEN`
- use `READ` instead of `READ-LINE`

Example:

```
CL-USER 11 > (let ((*read-eval* nil))
               (with-open-file (in "/tmp/test.data")
                 (read in)))
(1 2 3)

CL-USER 12 > (let ((*read-eval* nil))
               (with-open-file (in "/tmp/test.data")
                 (describe (read in))))

(1 2 3) is a LIST
0      1
1      2
2      3
```

Comment: `("((5 3 1))") is a list of length 1.` It's getting treated exactly as i don't want it to. How can i a make 5 3 1 separate list atoms?

Comment: So the mistake of mine is the way i am initializing the `originalStateVar` ? It's a little harsh for me to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: @MrDiaman You seem to be using `READ-LINE` (which returns a line of text as a string) rather than `READ` (which reads Lisp objects).